# Oracle Apex: how to populate data manually in editable IG

Tags: oracle-apex, populate, interactive-grid

we have a requirement to manually populate editable IG with data from another table when user press a button to fill rows.
IG is based on a table and a where clause is used but initially when appear the grid is empty, user will press a button and through a **process / procedure / fuction / dynamic action** this IG should be populated. please help how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

create a button with the action defined by dynamic action and create a duplicate IG region with data populated.
When this button is pressed, hide the empty Ig region and show the populated one.

Comment: thanks @cengiz sevimli , but this will need to have data in table first? i want to populate data from another table without first having it in target table may be through JS. i don't know much about JS but have some working knowledge of PL/SQL.

Comment: OK then you need an intermediate table for the data with the same columns of the target table. Think it like I have col1, col2 on target_table and col1 and col2 in medior_table. When user clicks to button I mentioned above, show the data from medior_table and on the save IG data process, create a custom function or code block that will save the data to target_table. In other words you will 1 custom fetch data process on page load and 1 custom process for saving which you will map the data to target_table like insert into target_table(col1) values (:col1).

Comment: yes, this kind of work around sounds good. i will check it on my test workspace at apex.oracle.com and if I achieve what is required, will implement in real app. thanks again for your valuable time and efforts to help me. regards